# how to call overridden function in titanium alloy controller

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

Alright so I've recently discovered how to inherit and override(if necessary) functions in Alloy controllers using exports.BaseController. So now I have this view page that contains a table whose rows are dynamically generated. Here's the xml view file and the associated controller file(part of it) below:

### parentView.xml

```
<Alloy>
<Window id="currentWin">
    <LeftNavButton>
        <Button  id="backBtn" onClick="goBack"/>
    </LeftNavButton>
    <TitleControl>
        <Label id="titleLabel"/>
    </TitleControl>
    <TableView id="menuTable"/>
</Window>
</Alloy>
```

### parentView.js

```
var dataArray = [];

var generateRows = function(){
//code to create a number of TableViewRow instances and push them into dataArray

};

exports.generateRows = generateRows;
generateRows();   //problem area

$.menuTable.setData(dataArray);
```

Now here is the controller that I'm using to inherit the above genrateRows function and override its functionality:

### childView.js

```
exports.baseController = "parentView";

var generateMyRows = function() {
//code to create a number of TableViewRow instances and push them into dataArray
};
exports.generateRows = generateMyRows;
```

My understanding of overriding using the exports.baseController in childView.js is that when the `generateRows()` call(problem area)  is made, the `generateMyRows()` method of childView.js is called. However this is not the case. The tableview is still getting populated by the `generateRows()` function of parentView.js. Please help me out, I've been breaking my head over this for hours!

Answer (score 1):

Bit late but if you call $.generateRows() it should work fine.